# bootstrap 4 modal - move buttons inside modal to left

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I have a modal I am using in bootstrap 4, however I like to move the 'cancel' and return buttons to the left side of the modal. I have a working js fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsolis/08v6znox/. Here is also my html code:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The general modal the docs provide [here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/) already does what I need it to, it's just figuring out how to make the buttons on the modal float left that are an issue. I've tried attaching the class `pull-left` to the buttons, but with no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overwrite the default Bootstrap css.

Just add this in your css:

```
.modal-footer {
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fd8256xk/).

You can read more about Bootstrap suite of responsive flexbox utilities here https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

Do not override the modal-footer class, this will effect all other modals as well.

You can simply achieve what you want by using Bootstrap itself:

```
<div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-start">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
```

You can read more about `d-flex justify-content-start` in the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content).